# RTC calibration - PPM offset to adjust clock rate faster/slower, by how much?

Tags: rtc, msp432

I have a TI MSP432P401R board. I have looked through the various other questions related to RTC calibration and I have not found an answer to this seemingly simple question.

The MSP432 SDK driverlib provides two ways to adjust the RTC calibration. The clock source is the external 32 kHz crystal. There are two calibration adjustments, that take either a +1 or a -1 ppm as the direction and then multiply that by an offset of 1 - 240.

The [MSP432 peripheral driverlib User's Guide](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/content/simplelink_msp432p4_sdk_3_40_01_02/docs/driverlib/msp432p4xx/MSP432_DriverLib_Users_Guide-MSP432P4xx-4_40_00_03.pdf) describes the temperature calibration routine, but the `rtc.h` contains a separate, but almost identical function that is not related to temperature.

The User's Guide and the header contain the same explanation of the functions use, e.g.

```c
//*****************************************************************************
//
//! Sets the specified temperature compensation for the RTC.
//!
//! \param offsetDirection is the direction that the calibration offset will
//!        go. Valid values are
//!        - \b   RTC_C_COMPENSATION_DOWN1PPM - calibrate at steps of -1
//!        - \b   RTC_C_COMPENSATION_UP1PPM - calibrate at steps of +1
//! \param offsetValue is the value that the offset will be a factor of; a
//!       value is any integer from 1-240.
//!
//! This function sets the calibration offset to make the RTC as accurate as
//! possible. The offsetDirection can be either +1-ppm or -1-ppm, and the
//! offsetValue should be from 1-240 and is multiplied by the direction setting
//! (i.e. +1-ppm * 8 (offsetValue) = +8-ppm).
//!
//! \return true if calibration was set, false if it could not be set
//!
//
//*****************************************************************************
extern bool RTC_C_setTemperatureCompensation(uint_fast16_t offsetDirection,
        uint_fast8_t offsetValue);
```

The second function contains an identical description save and except the temperature verbiage and has the declaration of:

```c
//*****************************************************************************
//
//! Sets the specified calibration for the RTC.
//! ... rest is the same ...
//*****************************************************************************
extern void RTC_C_setCalibrationData(uint_fast8_t offsetDirection,
        uint_fast8_t offsetValue);
```

The [TI MSP432 Technical Reference](https://academics.uccs.edu/mlaubhan/common/MSP432/slau356e.pdf) adds a bit of additional information, explaining that a +1 ppm offset will increase the clock frequency, while a -1 will decrease the clock frequency. The relevant information from the Technical Reference is:

[image]

That seems to explain that adding to the oscillator frequency will speed the clock up (more ticks per second, clock clicks off time faster), etc. However, there is no explanation of how to arrive at how much to compensate.

*How to determine the OffsetValue for clock calibration?*

This is where I'm confused. I don't know how the calibration of +ppm or -ppm will impact the clock rate (likely due to unfamiliarity with the jargon, Aero background, not EE).

Since I'm looking to compensate for the RTC running roughly 0.4 s too fast over 10 hours, how do you go about arriving at the `OffsetValue`?

Ideally we have 32768 cycles per second for the oscillator (or one tick per 3.051758 · 10<sup>-5</sup> seconds). The 0.4 s drift over 10 hours gives roughly a drift of 1.11111 · 10<sup>-5</sup> drift per second.

Where I'm lost is: how does a ppm relate to either value or their difference? Is there a way to take this information and arrive at a proper `OffsetValue` between 1 and 240 for the clock calibration?

---

**Update**

From further looking it seems we can compute ppm from Actual Frequency (F<sub>a</sub>) and Nominal Frequency (F<sub>nom</sub>), where the actual frequency F<sub>a</sub> = F<sub>nom</sub> · (1 + drift). In this case the Actual Frequency would be 32768.364088 Hz.

Then to find the PPM difference you would have:

$$\begin{align}
\small PPM & = \frac{F_a - F_{nom}}{F_{nom}} \cdot 10^6\\
& = drift \cdot 10^6\\
& = 11.1 
\end{align}$$

So roughly 11 ppm. In this case then, the direction would be -1 and the `OffsetValue` would be 11? Is that right (sane)?

---

**Result**

That in fact was the correct direction and roughly the correct `OffsetValue`. Given that the exact drift was an *"eyeball"* measurement of the difference between two running clocks, the true drift was probably closer to 0.2 to 0.3 s over 10 hours because after adjusting the clock as per above, the clock did slow and the drift was reduced, but it overshot a perfect correction.

After running the same test overnight, this time the clock lost 0.1 s over 12 hour, a four-fold improvement. So instead of an `OffsetValue` of 11 ppm, the actual `OffsetValue` needed looks between 6 ppm and 9 ppm.

We will re-run the test with an `OffsetValue` of 7 ppm and I suspect that will put the clock dead-on or close enough for the longest expected runtime for this microcontroller project where a user would not notice any drift in the clock. Less than a 0.1 second drift over 12-hours is well within acceptable margins here, and much better than the range of accuracy of a non-oven-controlled 32 kHz crystal. The reference for both the PPM calculations and the varying tolerances of different oscillators were taken from [Clock accuracy in ppm](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/ppm.html).

If there is anything unexpected in this next test, I'll update, otherwise, this matter is resolved. If someone would like to write up an answer that corrects any of the observations or material referenced here, I will gladly select it.

Comment: 1 ppm is just 1e-6 of relative rate.

Comment: @hobbs - yes, thank you, I caught the error in the factoring above. I've whittled down the `OffsetValue` to `5` where he clock is within `0.1`sec slow over 29 hours. I'll test with `4` just to find the where the slow-to-fast breakpoint is. But honestly, drift being within a fraction of one second in 29 hours is acceptable for the length of time this will run. The ultimate solution if longer runtime is wanted will by to write code to sync the time from an external source daily. The external 32KHz crystal on this board is fine with a time sync every 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Ppm (part-per-million) denotes a ratio that is scaled to a value (`10**6`) and is dimensionless. (i.e. like a percentage which is a ratio scaled to `10**2`)

Since the clock frequency describes how many ticks happen per second, the clock drift can be measured either in terms of frequency deviation or in terms of time differences. Both methods are equivalent.

With the MSP432 you can use any of them.

---

With the MSP432 you can enable the `RTCCLK` pin to output a frequency that is derived from the nominal RTC 32768 kHz oscillator (i.e. either 512 Hz, 256 Hz or 1 Hz, cf. the RTCCALF[1..0] bits in the RTCCTL3 register).

Thus, you can enable - say - a 512 Hz signal and measure it using a good enough frequency counter or oscilloscope and compare it against the nominal frequency. If the RTC oscillator drifts then you can also observe the drift in the derived frequency.

```
drift_corr_ppm = (f_meas / f_nom - 1) * 10**6
```

Example: `(512.00569 Hz / 512 Hz - 1) * 10**6 ~= 11.11 ppm`

After applying the calibration offset you should measure a frequency that deviates less from the nominal frequency (because the `RTCCLK` signal is also affected by the correction).

---

Alternatively, you can simply measure the clock offset and compute the ratio from that:

```
drift_corr_ppm = (ticks_meas / ticks_nom - 1) * 10**6

where
    ticks_meas = ticks_nom + ticks_offset_meas
```

Example: `((10 * 3600 s + 0.4 s) / (10 * 3600 s) - 1) * 10**6 ~= 11.11 ppm`

That means you can either directly count the ticks from the enabled `RTCCLK` pin and compare it against the counted ticks of a precise (enough) reference clock - or you can simply compare the clock's time after a (long enough) period with a reference clock to determine the offset (in seconds), directly.

---

Regarding terminology: With the MSP432, the `RTCOCALS` bit in the `RTCOCAL` register specifies the sign of the calibration offset:

- if set to `1` this denotes a negative offset, i.e. some ticks are 'stolen' during a calibration cycle, i.e. the frequency is sped up (up calibration) -> for correcting a RTC that is going too slow
- if set to `0` this denotes a positive offset, i.e. some extra ticks are injected during a calibration cycle, i.e. the frequency is slowed down (down calibration) -> for correcting an RTC that is going too fast

---

Note that the frequency drift of the RTC oscillator isn't constant. It changes as it ages and depends non-linearly on its temperature.

Since the MSP432 even contains a temperature sensor, you could use it to approximate the ambient temperature (and thus the temperature of the RTC oscillator) and thus (try to) compensate also for temperature changes, to some extent (cf. the `RTCTCMP` register and its discussion in the reference manual).